# Using index function and matching to determine a value out of range then outputting the corresponding value in the same column

Tags: excel, indexing, matching

I am trying to determine how to output a specific value that corresponds to a value that is out of range. I have a column (D) in excel with a normal range between 90 and 110. If there are values outside of that range I want to find the first value in column D and use the corresponding value in column A to denote the out of range value.

The formula I currently have to find the out of range value is

```
=(INDEX(D8:D17,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(D8:D17>110,0),0)))
```

This finds the first value that is greater that 110 however I do not know how to incorporate the <90 criteria into the formula and how to output the values from that same row from column A.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer AGGREGATE to MATCH(INDEX()):

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($D$8:$D$18)/(($D$8:$D$18>110)+($D$8:$D$18<90)),1))
```

This will find the first row in which the value in D is either greater than 110 or less than 90.

[image]

Comment: What is the main difference between aggregate and match? And that works perfect thank you very much!

Comment: @AndyMorrison personal preference, I find it easier to understand.  You could do it with the INDEX like this `=INDEX(A8:A18,MATCH(1,INDEX(($D$8:$D$18>110)+($D$8:$D$18<90),0),0))`  The `+` means `OR`

Comment: @AndyMorrison if it works and you use it please mark as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer.

Comment: That's great thank you for the quick response. I have one other quick question about this. If I wanted to take the value above in cell A (so 7 rather than 8) is that a simple addition into the formula or is that complex to input?

Comment: Nope easy for both you   place a `-1` behind the aggregate or the match formula and before the last `)`

Comment: Everything works perfectly I really appreciate the help @ScottCraner!